# Retain input value on a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

When a value is entered into an input and I open the window in a new tab, I would like that value to still be shown on the new tab.

Is this possible to use `window.localStorage` to achieve this?

Please see [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-save-input-value)

```
<input style="border: red solid 2px;" placeholder=" enter text...">
  <button id="btn" style="background:red" 
     (click)="openNewTab()" routerLink="/{{ href }}">
    Open-In-New-Tab >
  </button>
```

```
export class About{
  title: string = "About Page.";
    public href: String = '';

    constructor(private router: Router, private route:ActivatedRoute)
{ }
  openNewTab() {
    window.open('' + this.href + '?show=false', '_blank').focus();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.href = decodeURI(this.router.url.replace(/\/.*\//g, ''));
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params.show === 'false') {
        document.getElementById('navigation').outerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('btn').outerHTML = '';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Actual result:
The input value disappears in the new tab.

Expected result:
The newly opened tab should retain the input value

Comment: `localStorage` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, you can achieve this with `window.localStorage`, how ever I would suggest you to use `window.sessionStorage`. I will explain why at the end of a post.

You will have to use `(change)` event on input in order to save the value you entered. You will also have to add `[(ngModel)]` to the `<input>`

*Template*

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (change)="setValue($event.target.value)">
```

*Component*

```
export class MyComponent {
  inputValue = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('savedValue');
  }

  setValue(value) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('savedValue', value);
  }
}
```

This will retain the value when you open a new tab. How ever bear in mind that the value will also be retained if you refresh the initial page. If you use `sessionStorage` the value will be gone if you reopen your browser. With `localStorage` that wouldn't be the case as `localStorage` never expires.

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-save-input-value-qr2mqt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

If you want the value to be there **ONLY** when the page is reopened in a tab, I would suggest you to pass it as a Query string in URL. Then in Angular you will look if that query string exists in a URL and show the value (Either coming straight from a query string, or from storage)